# How to distinguish between "Ad Hoc" and "App Store" Code Signing Identities in xcconfig files?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, code-signing, xcodebuild, xcconfig

I'm trying to set up a Unity iOS project to run automated builds through Jenkins.  So far, I've got Jenkins triggering a Unity build, which generates an XCode project.  Then, using xcodebuild with XCode 4.5.2, I'm trying to generate an Ad-Hoc IPA file for distribution on Testflight.

In order to specify the code signing identity in the XCode project, I'm passing a very simple xcconfig file to xcodebuild.  The xcconfig file looks like this:

```
//:configuration = Release
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Distribution: Company Name

//:completeSettings = none
```

The problem I have is that "iPhone Distribution: Company Name" is ambiguous; it refers to both the "Ad Hoc" and "App Store" code signing identities.  And, of course, when I run the build, XCode chooses the App Store identity over Ad-Hoc, which is the opposite of what I'd like in this case.

Is there any way to specify that I'd like to use the Ad-Hoc identity through the xcconfig file?  It seems really odd that I wouldn't be able to explicitly specify the identity in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use Unity nor TestFlight yet.

But the general solution would be to use two different AppIds for AdHoc and AppStore. This way  xCode can automatically select the right one.